# Import.io Data Extractor

Tags: import.io

I would like to extract data from a website **http://www.talkingcock.com/html/lexec.php?op=LexView&lexicon=lexicon&alpha=A&page=1**. The output that I want would be a csv file with multiple rows, each row representing a word stated in the website. However, the results returned were: a few rows with all the words lumped into 1 row and a few rows with each word being 1 word. Do anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually there is an issue if the website is not properly structured and have issues differing the different variables on a website. I would suggest using Regex or XPaths to get data from this website.

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the proper parts for your columns and rows. eg. create a column for 'word' and only select one example of a word (eg. "A BIT THE"), choose 'Many Rows' as your row setting. import.io should preview and highlight other similar elements - you might have to highlight a couple more to 'train' your data. Then add a new column if you would like to extract the definition (or any other data associated with your word) as well. Its working here but you have to exclude the menu on the top.